# How to call only method of a grails controller with JavaScript file?

Tags: javascript, grails, methods, controller, http-status-code-404

I have a JavaScript file that calls a method of the Grails controller by ajax , but I have to create the `Login.gsp`. I do not want to create this view.

```
Ext.Ajax.request({
 url: 'user/login', 
 params: {
   user: user,
   password: pass
 }
});
```

The method is called, but in Chrome console have the output:

`POST localhost:8080/myapp/user/login 404 (Not Found)`

Answer (score 2):

You dont have to create a view for it. Add a "login" method in your UserController and return a JSON result

```
class UserController{

  def login(){
    //Your code...
    render result as JSON
  }
}
```

If you are using SpringSecurity make sure that the login method is accesible for non-authenticated users.

Comment: Thanks @agusluc, i resolved, I tried using the `render(status: 200, text: "ok")` and it worked : D

Comment: Glad to hear. My suggestion of rendering json content instead of a request with plain text is for take advantage of the grails validation messages and the i18n support while using AJAX